# How can I compare normals in AN with python

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I am trying to create a script that assigns a differente rotation to polys according to their normals but I can´t figure out how to do it. This is my script so far.

```
import math
import mathutils


mirando_arriba = mathutils.Vector((0.0000,0.0000,1.0000))
mirando_derecha = mathutils.Vector((0.0000,1.0000,0.0000))
mirando_izquierda = mathutils.Vector((-0.0000,-1.0000,-0.0000))
mirando_abajo = mathutils.Vector((0.0000,0.0000,-1.0000))
mirando_fondo = mathutils.Vector((1.0000,0.0000,0.0000))
mirando_trasera = mathutils.Vector((-1.0000,0.0000,-0.0000))
if (Normal == mirando_arriba):
    result = rotateY
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia arriba"
elif (Normal ==  mirando_derecha):
    result = rotateX
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia derecha"
elif (Normal ==  mirando_abajo):
    result = rotateX
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia abajo"   
elif (Normal ==  mirando_fondo):
    result = rotateX     
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia fondo" 
elif (Normal ==  mirando_izquierda):
    result = rotateX     
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia izquierda" 
elif (Normal ==  mirando_trasera):
    result = rotateY     
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia trasera"     
else:
    result = rotateY
    TextBlock = "No mira"
```

Comment: By polys do you mean faces? Or mesh objects?

Comment: Yes I mean faces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue I see here is comparing vectors that are float vectors and that can give false negatives.

For vector comparison it's better to use "distance", rather than "==".
(Also, in blender precision appears to go up to 6, so use at most < 0.00001)

For more see: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/327

---

However, that means in your code:

```
if (Normal - mirando_arriba).length_squared < 0.0001:
    result = rotateY
    TextBlock = "Mira hacia arriba"
```

and same for the rest.

Comment: For better peformance you can also use (...).length_squared. (This is faster because it doesn't have to calculate the square root of the distance internally.) http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.length_squared